# response from server width jquery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

i can use this below code for sending any data to server and getting successful result, but my code dont sent respond `$data` is true or false.
code is can successful insert to database
localhost PHP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.post("http://www.test.com/index.php",  {userCode:"ttt-ddd-fff"},
            function(data){  
                alert (data.message);
            },'json');  
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Server:

```
<?php
include_once ('./AFactory.class.php');
$database= new AFactory;
$db=new AFactory();
$link=$db->getDBO();
$query=array('id'=>NULL,'userCode'=>$_POST['userCode']);
$sql=$db->insertQuery(' `test`.`users`',$query);
if ( mysql_query($sql) ) 
    {$data['success']=true;$data['message']='ok';}
else 
    {$data['success']=false;$data['message']='no';}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Can you console.log() the return data? Do it and paste your return data here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using

```
alert (data.success);
```

rather than

```
alert (data.message);
```

Comment: Are you able to use firebug to see what the response is from the server?

Comment: `POST http://........../index.php 200 OK
jquery-1.8.2.js (line 8416)
HeadersPostResponseHTML
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
userCode ttt-ddd-fff
Source userCode=ttt-ddd-fff` Response is empty

Comment: Have you run the PHP page manually to make sure you are getting the expected output?

Comment: in running manually that showing OK, but in ajax thats not responsing